# Why can I not import the Python module 'signal' using Jython, in Linux?

Tags: python, jython, signals

I can't find any reference to the 'signal' class being left out in Jython. Using Jython 2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine Unix-style signals are difficult to do on the JVM, since the JVM has no notion of signals, and it is likely some JNI magic would be required to get this to work.

In Jython 2.5, the module exists, but seems to throw `NotImplementedError` for most functions.

Comment: ahhhhhhh noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying implement an execution time-limit on a script, incase infinite loops are encountered or such.

Comment: @Leonidas: Search for that exact issue as a separate question.  It's been asked at least a half-dozen times on SO.

Comment: yeah I have but I'm specifically trying to do it from Jython on Win & Unix (means no using signal.alarm()) and it has to be done on the whole script, not just a function. I get the script from the text editor of an application and have to parse / edit it to include the time-limit execution code.